# Flutter: Focus keyboard on back navigation

Tags: dart, uinavigationbar, flutter, viewdidappear

I want to focus a textField after the user navigated back with the back button in the navigation bar. How do you do that? I tried the `autofocus` property of the `TextField` widget. But this only works when navigating forward when the widget gets created for the first time. On iOS there is the `viewDidAppear` method, is there something similar in Flutter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide your `TextField` a `FocusNode`, and then you can `await` the user to go back and set `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myNode)` when the navigation happens.

Simple demonstration:

[image]

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => new _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  FocusNode n = new FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title:new Text("First Page")),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              focusNode: n,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(onPressed: ()async{

              bool focus = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new SecondPage()));
              if (focus == true|| focus==null){

                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(n);

              }
              },
            child: new Text("NAVIGATE"),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title:new Text("Second Page")),
    body: new Center(
      child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context,true);},child: new Text("BACK"),),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is good to note that the value of `focus` is `null` when the back button is pressed (as shown in the gif). It is `true` when the 'BACK' `RaisedButton` is pressed.